# Meta question on Stack Exhange Android app

Tags: discussion, android-app, stack-exchange

How come when I click on "download the Android app for Stack Exchange" in a mail of Stack Overflow, I arrive on Google Play and it tells me there is no such app? Is there really no app for Stack Exhange Q&A websites? How come?

Comment: While being closed as a duplicate, this certainly is a bug with the wording of the email you received, as there is no sense in pointing to a non-existent app. Was it a recent email?

Comment: Yeah actually it was, less than 24h ago

Comment: I would say make a bug report about this, the link in the email, on meta.StackOverflow.